Oracle SQL Join 2 tables without ID
Table 1: CHECKPOINTS



ID
NAME




1
School


2
Library


3
Parking



Table 2: STUDENTS



ID
NAME




1000
John


1001
Mike


1002
Peter


1003
Mark



Table 3: STUDENT_CHECKPOINTS



ID
STUDENT_ID
CHECKPOINT_ID
IS_CLEAR




1
1000
1
1


2
1000
2
2


3
1000
3
1


4
1001
2
1


5
1001
3
2


6
1002
3
1



Table 3 is filled in only when students are assigned a status IS_CLEAR (1 - Approved, 2 - Not approved)
How to make the resulting query that adds records of not set statuses?
I want to get this result:



STUDENT_ID
CHECKPOINT_ID
IS_CLEAR




1000
1
1


1000
2
2


1000
3
1


1001
1
0


1001
2
1


1001
3
2


1002
1
0


1002
2
0


1002
3
1




You could generate records for all STUDENTS and CHECKPOINTS by using CROSS JOIN. Use that to LEFT JOIN the STUDENT_CHECKPOINTS to it and replace null values with 0:
WITH ALL_CHECKPOINTS AS (
  SELECT 
    STUDENTS.ID AS STUDENT_ID,
    CHECKPOINTS.ID AS CHECKPOINT_ID
  FROM STUDENTS CROSS JOIN CHECKPOINTS 
)

SELECT 
  ALL_CHECKPOINTS.STUDENT_ID, 
  ALL_CHECKPOINTS.CHECKPOINT_ID, 
  NVL(STUDENT_CHECKPOINTS.IS_CLEAR, 0) AS IS_CLEAR
FROM ALL_CHECKPOINTS
LEFT JOIN STUDENT_CHECKPOINTS
ON  ALL_CHECKPOINTS.STUDENT_ID = STUDENT_CHECKPOINTS.STUDENT_ID
AND ALL_CHECKPOINTS.CHECKPOINT_ID = STUDENT_CHECKPOINTS.CHECKPOINT_ID


This query is not correct

What do you mean by not correct.

I created a dbfiddle for you. I'm pretty sure it does what it needs to do. https://dbfiddle.uk/cpzYqE_I

Your answer is good! I just simplified it

    SELECT ALL_CHECKPOINTS.*, NVL(STUDENT_CHECKPOINTS.IS_CLEAR, 0) AS IS_CLEAR  FROM ( 
       SELECT 
        STUDENTS.ID AS STUDENT_ID,
        CHECKPOINTS.ID AS CHECKPOINT_ID
       FROM STUDENTS CROSS JOIN CHECKPOINTS 
    ) ALL_CHECKPOINTS 
    LEFT JOIN STUDENT_CHECKPOINTS ON STUDENT_CHECKPOINTS.STUDENT_ID =  ALL_CHECKPOINTS.STUDENT_ID AND STUDENT_CHECKPOINTS.CHECKPOINT_ID = ALL_CHECKPOINTS.CHECKPOINT_ID
ORDER BY 1,2


Is it worse than yours?

It's the same. I like using a CTE for readability
